# Light a candle or burn a candle

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

What is more common "light" or "burn" in this context?

> Do you know how to **burn** a candle?
>
> Do you know how to **light** a candle?

Are either of them equally likely?

Comment: You do not give the context. To light a candle means to set the wick aflame. To burn a candle means to allow a lit candle to burn down. Which one you prefer depends on what you want to say.

Comment: I mean the first one. @Ronald Sole.

Comment: Would you mind looking this stuff up before posting? This is available online.

Answer (score 1):

**Lighting** the candle is ignition, the starting process, which you might ask a child if they know how to do.  **Burning** the candle is the period while you let it stay lit, with almost no learning required.

So the normal sentence would be:

- **Do you know how to light a candle?**

Answer (score 0):

Candles are *lit*. Burning something implies consuming it and making it no more, while lighting something involves implies it a carrier of fire without directly intending for it to become consumed.