# Burn a fire or light a fire?

Tags: word-usage, american-english

[Light a candle or burn a candle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208481/light-a-candle-or-burn-a-candle) says "Light a candle" and "burn a candle" are both grammartically OK.

In the [dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/light_3) I see "light a fire". Then is "burn a fire" ok?

I think candle (reason) leads to fire (result). Reason and result can both follow "light", how about "burn"?

Comment: No, logic doesn't work when it comes to expressions. You cannot burn a fire. You can only burn objects in a fire. People will know what you mean by **burn a fire** but you are just displaying your ignorance of English idiom.

Comment: @RonaldSole I see "fire" has another meaning "a piece of equipment for heating a room". Can you help me play with these words? Like "I have a broken electric fire. I light the fire. I burn the fire in fire. I light the fire in water, but the fire does not burn."

Comment: "electric fire" doesn't make any sense in US English, because *fire* literally means *flames*.